# Application on server

Tags: iphone, android, sql-server

I want to put my android application on server and i used .apk file for that.
But our admin wants a plist file as of in iphone.

I dono what is plist in android and how to generate it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.plist files are the Mac version of preference files. Similar to .ini files on Windows. They contain the preferences for a particular program. For example the bookmarks.plist would contain your bookmarks.

Android applications usually(but not stricted to) store their preferences in the xml file with name, defined by developers. Tell your admins that the file is not necessary for an android application.